# Client validation for EditorFor in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have an EditorFor template for date which consists of three dropdowns(mm,dd,yyyy). Below is the class for the same which consists of some validations working fine

```
public class DateDDL
    {
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Days { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Months { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Years { get; set; }

        [Attributes.DateDDLValidation("Day", "Month", "Year", ErrorMessage = "Select day")]
        public int Day { get; set; }

        [Attributes.DateDDLValidation("Day", "Month", "Year", ErrorMessage = "Select month")]
        public int Month { get; set; }

        [Attributes.DateDDLValidation("Day", "Month", "Year", ErrorMessage = "Select year")]
        public int Year { get; set; }
}
```

But now i have to write a validation in model class for the same editorfor which is something like below

```
  public partial class User
    {
        public DateDDL DOBDDL { get; set; }

        [pmrms.Attributes.DateGreaterThanToday(ErrorMessage="testting")]
        public DateDDL JoinedOnDDL { get; set; }
}
```

But client validation for this is not able set or not working. GetClientValidationRules method is not loading in custom validator class

```
 protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage);
        }
        public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
        {
            return new[] { new ModelClientValidationDateGreaterThanToday(ErrorMessage) };
        }
        public class ModelClientValidationDateGreaterThanToday : ModelClientValidationRule
        {
            public ModelClientValidationDateGreaterThanToday(string errorMessage)
            {
                ErrorMessage = errorMessage; 
            }
        }
```

Comment: Is that IsValid method complete? I can see you don't use the value in your return new ValidationResult(...). Do I miss something?

Comment: ValidationResult function is now not checking the logic, I was just checking.. But I am getting here values in properties of editorfor class (DateDDL), means we can make server validation work. only client validation is the issue.